# Определение ip адреса виртуальной машины

Tags: linux, virtualbox, виртуальная-машина, gnome, ip-address

Установил виртуальную машину https://www.1c-bitrix.ru/download/vmbitrix.php и gnome для неё (графический интерфейс). Каким образом в gnome можно определить ip адрес машины (c помощью каких пунктов меню и каких команд)?

Comment: https://tecadmin.net/check-ip-address-centos8/

Comment: как и всегда: `$ ip a`

Comment: Пожалуйста, не используй гуй для настройки серверных штук. Потому что на проде никто не использует гном. Все юзают шелл и тектовые файлы. Привыкай сразу к хорошему.

Answer (score 1):

Меню где кнопка выключения, там кнопка параметры, дальше сеть, на активном подключении нажать на шестеренку и там на первой вкладке будет ip адрес.

Или `ip a` в терминале.